# Data table is not working while tr collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Data table is not working while added a collapse `tr`. If remvoe collapse `tr` then data table is working properly how to fix it anybody can help
Thanks in advance...

```js
$('.tableToggleUl').parent('td').css('padding','0px');
        $('.tableToggleUl').hide();
        $('.tableToggleBtn').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('.tableToggleUl').toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus-circle, fa-minus-circle');
        });
        $('.tableToggleBtn').next('.iconConfirmedAppointments, .fa-clock-o, .iconPracticeRescheduled').css('float','left');
        $('.tableToggleBtn').parent('td').css('width','65px');




  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnApptSuggestion').on("click",function(){

            $validator = $('#frmSuggestionAppt').validate();
            $validator.resetForm();

            var AppID=$(this).data('value');
            var patientID=$(this).data('patient');
            var parentId=$(this).data('parentid');
            var AppointmentDate=$(this).data('sugdate');
               
            $('#SuggestionAppointmentID').val(AppID);
            $('#SuggestPatientID').val(patientID);
            $('#SuggestOtherPatientID').val(parentId);
            $('#dateAppointment').val(AppointmentDate);
        });
        try
        {
            var dTable = $('.reportTable').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "bSortable": false,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[20, 30, 50], [20, 30, 50]]
            });
        }
        catch(e)
        {

        }

 });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover dr-table datatable reportTable dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0">
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding-left:36px;" class="sorting_disabled">Status</th>
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;" class="sorting_disabled">Slot Type</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled">Professional</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled">Patient</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled">Date &amp; time</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled">Checked In</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled">Checked Out</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row">
                            
                                <td style="width: 65px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus tableToggleBtn" style="cursor:pointer;"></span><div class="icon iconConfirmedAppointments" 

style="float: left;"></div></td>
                                                            <td><div class="icon iconPatientWithSlot"></div></td>
                            <td>Dr. Doctor Testing </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/doctor/patient_detail?encryptid=vkK6vkgyyNyMuKJi1qDQuw%3D%3D">

                                    Miss. Kratika  Aggrawal Sr.

                                </a>
                            </td>
                                <td>July 19 2017 - 11:00 AM</td>
                            <td>
                                
                                                            </td>
                            <td>
                                
                            </td>
                                <td>
                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
                                                <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </a>
                                            <style>
                                                @media only screen and (min-width:150px) and (max-width:991px) {
                                                    .table .dropdown-menu {
                                                        left: 0px !important;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            </style>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <input type="hidden" value="77" class="Status">
                                                        <input type="hidden" value="8886" class="ID">
                                                        <input type="hidden" class="ParentPatientID">
                                                        <a class="lnkChangeStatus" href="#" style="width:auto;">Appointment Status</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <input type="hidden" value="8886" class="ID">
                                                        <a href="/doctor/dr_otherappointment?encryptid=vkK6vkgyyNyMuKJi1qDQuw%3D%3D" style="width:auto;">Outgoing Referrals</a>
                                                    </li>


                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                </td>


                        </tr>
<tr>
                            <td colspan="8" style="padding: 0px;">
                                <ul class="tableToggleUl">

                                    <li>
                                        <label>Report Status</label>
                                            <span></span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Record Uploaded</label>
                                            <span>No</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Order Received</label>
                                            <span>No</span>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Authorization</label>
                                            <span>No</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="tableRow1Height">
                                        <label>Care Plan Uploaded</label>
                                            <span>No</span>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Guardian Name</label>
                                            <span></span>                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Referred By</label>
                                            <span>Miss. Kratika  Aggrawal Sr. (Patient)</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Insurance</label>
                                            <span></span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Visit Reason</label>
                                        <span>abdominal Pain</span>
                                    </li>

                                   
                                   
                                    
                                    <li>
                                        <label>How Did Hear</label>
                                        <span>Market Place</span>
                                    </li>
                                   
                                    <li>
                                        <label>Location</label>
                                        <span> Tester Rd  Snohomish Washington 98290</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [**dataTables does not work with colspan**](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan).  End of story :) Perhaps you do what you want using [**child rows**](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tableToggleBtn-tr").click(function(){
    $(".tableToggleUl-td").toggle();
  });
  $('.btnApptSuggestion').on("click", function() {

    $validator = $('#frmSuggestionAppt').validate();
    $validator.resetForm();

    var AppID = $(this).data('value');
    var patientID = $(this).data('patient');
    var parentId = $(this).data('parentid');
    var AppointmentDate = $(this).data('sugdate');

    $('#SuggestionAppointmentID').val(AppID);
    $('#SuggestPatientID').val(patientID);
    $('#SuggestOtherPatientID').val(parentId);
    $('#dateAppointment').val(AppointmentDate);
  });
  try {
    var dTable = $('.reportTable').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "bSortable": false,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "bRetrieve": true,
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bDestroy": true,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": false,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "responsive": true,
      "aLengthMenu": [
        [20, 30, 50],
        [20, 30, 50]
      ]
    });
  } catch (e) {

  }

});
```

```css
.tableToggleUl-td { display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dr-table datatable reportTable dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding-left:36px;" class="sorting_disabled">Status</th>
        <th style="white-space: nowrap;" class="sorting_disabled">Slot Type</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Professional</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Patient</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Date &amp; time</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Checked In</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Checked Out</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr role="row" class="tableToggleBtn-tr">

        <td style="width: 65px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus tableToggleBtn" style="cursor:pointer;"></span>
          <div class="icon iconConfirmedAppointments" style="float: left;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="icon iconPatientWithSlot"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Dr. Doctor Testing </td>
        <td>
          <a href="/doctor/patient_detail?encryptid=vkK6vkgyyNyMuKJi1qDQuw%3D%3D">

                                    Miss. Kratika  Aggrawal Sr.

                                </a>
        </td>
        <td>July 19 2017 - 11:00 AM</td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <style>
              @media only screen and (min-width:150px) and (max-width:991px) {
                .table .dropdown-menu {
                  left: 0px !important;
                }
              }
            </style>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <input type="hidden" value="77" class="Status">
                <input type="hidden" value="8886" class="ID">
                <input type="hidden" class="ParentPatientID">
                <a class="lnkChangeStatus" href="#" style="width:auto;">Appointment Status</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="hidden" value="8886" class="ID">
                <a href="/doctor/dr_otherappointment?encryptid=vkK6vkgyyNyMuKJi1qDQuw%3D%3D" style="width:auto;">Outgoing Referrals</a>
              </li>


            </ul>
          </div>
        </td>


      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8" style="padding: 0px;"  class="tableToggleUl-td">
          <ul class="tableToggleUl">

            <li>
              <label>Report Status</label>
              <span></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Record Uploaded</label>
              <span>No</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Order Received</label>
              <span>No</span>

            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Authorization</label>
              <span>No</span>
            </li>
            <li class="tableRow1Height">
              <label>Care Plan Uploaded</label>
              <span>No</span>

            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Guardian Name</label>
              <span></span> </li>
            <li>
              <label>Referred By</label>
              <span>Miss. Kratika  Aggrawal Sr. (Patient)</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Insurance</label>
              <span></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Visit Reason</label>
              <span>abdominal Pain</span>
            </li>




            <li>
              <label>How Did Hear</label>
              <span>Market Place</span>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>Location</label>
              <span> Tester Rd  Snohomish Washington 98290</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script enter code heresrc="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

hope its work

Comment: Please add a little description in addition to your code. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: First, set class so you can call them with JS because it wouldn't let me use parent or child and hide them.And CSS to hide them onload else they could see the hidden TDs. toggle method used in JS, on in each click it toggles the TD.

Comment: This answer is not related to my problem. Actually i used data-table in this but that is not working because of second tr is collapse. so how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here in Allan's reply: [DataTables and colspan](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan/p1).

Data table does not support `colspan`. The reason for this is that it is very much a non-trivial problem in how this would interact with filtering and sorting (for example how would you sort a column which has elements that span multiple columns - which column would that data belong to? The first one, or all of them? - The same question hangs over filtering).

And you are using `colspan` as we can see here:

```
<td colspan="8" style="padding: 0px;"  class="tableToggleUl-td">
```

This is the reason that the data table is not working at your end.

Although it is not an option right now, you can use their [Complex headers](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html). if you want table headers merged.